# Comparing dates in a query using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

How can I create a query like

`WHERE DATE(created_date) = '2014-05-26'`

in Laravel?

I got this

`->where('created_date', Input::get('date'))`

but it doesn't work because **created_date** is datetime

Comment: As Laravel requires Carbon, use it to parse the date.

Comment: `->where(DB::raw('DATE(created_date)'), Input::get('date'))`

Answer (score 2):

By using the DateTime class maybe :

```
->where('created_date', new DateTime(Input::get('date')))
```

It should work!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
where('created_date', '>', $date->startOfDay()->toDateTimeString())
->where('created_date', '<', $date->endOfDay()->toDateTimeString())
->get();
```

and take a look at this:
[Laravel eloquent get model on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231836/laravel-eloquent-get-model-on-date)

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert you string representation of the date into a Carbon instance.

```
$date    = Carbon\Carbon::parse(Input::get('date'));
$results = Model::where('created_date', $date);
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Wouldn't that be anyways `"2014-03-27 09:22:00" = "2014-03-27"`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option, and most logical one, is the following:

```
$results = Model::whereDate('created_date', Input::get('date'));
```

Use of Carbon is optional here.