# Laravel eloquent get model on date

Tags: php, datetime, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I want to get all users created on a specified date:

```
// $date is a Carbon instance parsed from command line argument.
// I checked it and it is correct.

$users = User::where('created_at', '>', $date->startOfDay())
    ->where('created_at', '<', $date->endOfDay())
    ->get();
```

But this returns 0 results, whereas in the database there are rows that correspond to that date.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Carbon` doesn't behave like value object (ie. it's not immutable), so this:

```
$date->startOfDay();
$date->endOfDay();
```

simply modifies the `$date` object and returns it back. That being said, the string that is passed to the query, is obtained when `PDO` binds it in the prepared statement, when `$date` is already mutated to `endOfDay`.

It means that you just pass reference to the object:

```
$start === $end; // true
```

So either use different objects:

```
$users = User::where('created_at', '>', $date->copy()->startOfDay())
  ->where('created_at', '<', $date->copy()->endOfDay())
  ->get();
```

or simply return the string you need in place, instead of the `Carbon` object:

```
$users = User::where('created_at', '>', $date->startOfDay()->toDateTimeString())
  ->where('created_at', '<', $date->endOfDay()->toDateTimeString())
  ->get();
```

still, `$date` will now hold `xxxx-xx-xx 23:59:59` timestamp, so keep this in mind in case you need to work with this variable somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not Laravel itself here but Carbon.

When using the following code:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
$date = new Carbon('2014-10-07');

$start = $date->startOfDay();

$end = $date->endOfDay();

echo $start.' '.$end;
```

what you get is:

```
2014-10-07 23:59:59 2014-10-07 23:59:59
```

so Laravel will execute query:

```
select * from `users` where `created_at` >'2014-10-07 23:59:59' and `created_at` <'2014-10-07 23:59:59';
```

and  obviously you will get no results.

As you see `$start` result is not what you expect here.

to make it work the solution I found is creating 2 carbon objects:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
$date = new Carbon('2014-10-07');
$date2 = new Carbon('2014-10-07');

$start = $date->startOfDay();

$end = $date2->endOfDay();

echo $start.' '.$end;
```

Now result is as expected:

```
2014-10-07 00:00:00 2014-10-07 23:59:59
```

Now you can use:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
$date = new Carbon('2014-10-07');
$date2 = new Carbon('2014-10-07');

$users = User::where('created_at', '>', $date->startOfDay())
    ->where('created_at', '<', $date2->endOfDay())
    ->get();
```

or

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
$date = new Carbon('2014-10-07');
$date2 = new Carbon('2014-10-07');

$users = User::whereBetween('created_at', [$date->startOfDay(), $date2->endOfDay()])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query lefts the table name:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('votes', '>', 100)
                ->orWhere('name', 'John')
                ->get();
```

Look: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects